# Как сделать resample по разным признакам с разными условиями?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как сделать resample данных по получасовому интервалу с использованием усреднения для признаков Temperature, Humidity,  Light, CO2, HumidityRatio. Обратить внимание, что столбец с метками класса Occupancy вместо усреднения нужно взять "как есть", т.е. resample c методом "asfreq" или "bfill".
Беру данные:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('datatraining.txt', sep=r',', engine='python', header=None, names = ['id', 'date','Temperature','Humidity','Light','CO2','HumidityRatio','Occupancy'])
    df = df.drop([0])
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
    df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
    df2 = df.copy()


id  Temperature Humidity    Light   CO2 HumidityRatio   Occupancy
date                            
2015-02-04 17:51:00 1   23.18   27.2720 426.0   721.25  0.004793    1.0
2015-02-04 17:51:59 2   23.15   27.2675 429.5   714.00  0.004783    1.0
2015-02-04 17:53:00 3   23.15   27.2450 426.0   713.50  0.004779    1.0
2015-02-04 17:54:00 4   23.15   27.2000 426.0   708.25  0.004772    1.0
2015-02-04 17:55:00 5   23.10   27.2000 426.0   704.50  0.004757    1.0




funcs = dict(Temperature ="mean", Humidity ="mean", Light="mean", CO2 ="mean", HumidityRatio ="mean",  Occupancy ="asfreq")
df2.resample('30min').agg(funcs)
```

Ошибка

```
Cannot access callable attribute 'asfreq' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' meth
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YzGDML_wBZSJTGip3yZ1uk6HTTCSg_nD/view?usp=sharing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как одновременно заполнить под задачу все столбцы?

Comment: Убираю столбец Occupancy из funcs - ошибки нет

Comment: Использую bfiil вместо asfreq - работает, но первый столбец NaN

Comment: Вот так заработало без asfreq:     `funcs = dict(Temperature ="mean", Humidity ="mean", Light="mean", CO2 ="mean", HumidityRatio ="mean",  Occupancy ="bfill")
df2.resample('30min').agg(funcs).dropna()`

Answer (score 1):

```
funcs = dict(Temperature ="mean", Humidity ="mean", Light="mean", CO2 ="mean", HumidityRatio ="mean", Occupancy ="bfill") 

df2.resample('30min').agg(funcs).dropna()
```